# Changing the arrow color in WPF Toolkit NumericUpDown control?

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, numericupdown

Is there a way with a style to target the arrows in the NumericUpDown control from the WPF Toolkit? I want to change the color of the arrows.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `GlyphNormalForeground` color.

you will have to add the `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Themes` xmnls namespace to your xaml.
(or WpfToolkit.Themes if your using the old version)

Example:

```
<Grid>
    <wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown  Margin="37,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static theme:ResourceKeys.GlyphNormalForegroundKey}"  Color="Red"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown.Style>
    </wpfToolkit:IntegerUpDown>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I added `xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Themes"` to the top, but when I try your code I get the error "The name 'ResourceKeys' does not exist in the namespace...". When I look at the Object Browser for the WPFToolkit.Extended reference I can see everything in there, so I don't know why it's not picking up on it.

Answer (score 1):

To add Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Themes namespace use this 
xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Themes;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"